# Where can I ask a question about color models and color matching?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, scope

I have a color matching question, it has to do with programming but it's more about finding an algorithm to render a weird color model in RGB space, and it's kind of an open-ended question.  I guess it's more on the graphics side (or maybe it's for ux.sx?). Is there a good SX site for this question?

Comment: I'm not sure about this, so I won't make it an answer, but maybe http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @Linuxios Thanks; that's probably as good a place to start as any. Alternatively, at the cost of limiting my options a little, I *could* formulate it as  a geometry/linear algebra question for math.sx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading through some of the content on *graphicdesign* (suggested by Linuxios in comments) and *UX*, I've decided that I can get the most bang for my buck by reformulating the question as a geometric question, which it is, and putting it on *math*.

I had to think for a minute and make some decisions about the approach I wanted to take for my problem, but when I did, it reduced to finding a function to map some specific 2D points to other 2D points. So, [math it is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/695511/deforming-2d-points-square-triangle).